# MongoDB Running sum over date range per ID

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb, nosql

I have the following json file (small sample) which consists of purchase records of 4 different customers across different dates. I am required to use MongoDB/nosql to identify which customers have made at least a total of 8 new purchases over a consecutive period of 3 days.

In this case, customer ABC made 32 total purchases from 2020-05-01 to 2020-05-03 (3 consecutive days). Customer GHI also had 20 purchases from 2020-07-28 to 2020-07-30 (3 consecutive days). So my output should only contain customers ABC and GHI. What would be the code to get the output? Many thanks!

```
{"cust_id":"ABC", "date":"2020-05-01", "new_purchase":2},
 {"cust_id":"ABC", "date":"2020-05-02", "new_purchase":16},
 {"cust_id":"ABC", "date":"2020-05-03", "new_purchase":14},
 {"cust_id":"ABC", "date":"2020-05-04", "new_purchase":0},
 {"cust_id":"ABC", "date":"2020-05-05", "new_purchase":5},
 {"cust_id":"DEF", "date":"2020-05-11", "new_purchase":3},
 {"cust_id":"DEF", "date":"2020-05-12", "new_purchase":0},
 {"cust_id":"DEF", "date":"2020-05-13", "new_purchase":0},
 {"cust_id":"DEF", "date":"2020-05-14", "new_purchase":0},
 {"cust_id":"DEF", "date":"2020-05-15", "new_purchase":1},
 {"cust_id":"GHI", "date":"2020-07-28", "new_purchase":0},
 {"cust_id":"GHI", "date":"2020-07-29", "new_purchase":3},
 {"cust_id":"GHI", "date":"2020-07-30", "new_purchase":17},
 {"cust_id":"GHI", "date":"2020-07-31", "new_purchase":0},
 {"cust_id":"GHI", "date":"2020-08-01", "new_purchase":1},
 {"cust_id":"JKL", "date":"2020-06-04", "new_purchase":7},
 {"cust_id":"JKL", "date":"2020-06-05", "new_purchase":0},
 {"cust_id":"JKL", "date":"2020-06-06", "new_purchase":0},
 {"cust_id":"JKL", "date":"2020-06-07", "new_purchase":0},
 {"cust_id":"JKL", "date":"2020-06-08", "new_purchase":0},
 {"cust_id":"JKL", "date":"2020-06-08", "new_purchase":2}
```

Comment: is date really a string or an ISO date?

Comment: Why do you ask the same question four(!) times? https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/279681/mongodb-running-sum-over-3-days-per-id https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/279664/mongodb-running-sum-over-3-days-for-each-customer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64831434/counting-number-of-consecutive-days-based-on-a-condition-in-mongodb https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64831527/mongodb-running-sum-over-date-range-per-id

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the days are not repeated, which seems to be the case as long as you have a typo in the last date.

---

The idea is:

1. Split the date, and group by year and month,
2. Inspect the days, and for each day we test if `day-1` and `day+1` exist. If they exist, we add it as an array to a set, like so: sets:`[[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [3,4,5]]`.
3. This array is `$unwind`ed, and we find the sum of the products for those days.
4. Only `total > 8` is matched.
5. If you want just one result per person add `{$group:{_id:"$id"}}`
6. [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-V3wRcyGb62)

```
    [
        {
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : {
                    "cust_id" : "$cust_id",
                    "year" : {
                        "$arrayElemAt" : [
                            {
                                "$split" : [
                                    "$date",
                                    "-"
                                ]
                            },
                            0
                        ]
                    },
                    "month" : {
                        "$arrayElemAt" : [
                            {
                                "$split" : [
                                    "$date",
                                    "-"
                                ]
                            },
                            1
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "daysAndBuys" : {
                    "$push" : {
                        "day" : {
                            "$convert" : {
                                "input" : {
                                    "$arrayElemAt" : [
                                        {
                                            "$split" : [
                                                "$date",
                                                "-"
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        2
                                    ]
                                },
                                "to" : "int"
                            }
                        },
                        "buys" : "$new_purchase"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$addFields" : {
                "sets" : {
                    "$map" : {
                        "input" : "$daysAndBuys",
                        "as" : "d",
                        "in" : {
                            "$cond" : [
                                {
                                    "$and" : [
                                        {
                                            "$in" : [
                                                {
                                                    "$add" : [
                                                        "$$d.day",
                                                        1
                                                    ]
                                                },
                                                "$daysAndBuys.day"
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "$in" : [
                                                {
                                                    "$subtract" : [
                                                        "$$d.day",
                                                        1
                                                    ]
                                                },
                                                "$daysAndBuys.day"
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                [
                                    "$$d.day",
                                    {
                                        "$add" : [
                                            "$$d.day",
                                            1
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "$subtract" : [
                                            "$$d.day",
                                            1
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ],
                                ""
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$addFields" : {
                "sets" : {
                    "$filter" : {
                        "input" : "$sets",
                        "as" : "s",
                        "cond" : {
                            "$ne" : [
                                "$$s",
                                ""
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$unwind" : "$sets"
        },
        {
            "$addFields" : {
                "daysAndBuys" : {
                    "$filter" : {
                        "input" : "$daysAndBuys",
                        "as" : "data",
                        "cond" : {
                            "$in" : [
                                "$$data.day",
                                "$sets"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$project" : {
                "daysAndBuys" : 1,
                "total" : {
                    "$sum" : "$daysAndBuys.buys"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$match" : {
                "total" : {
                    "$gte" : 8
                }
            }
        }
    ]
```